# Best .net 4.5 async method to know when multiple conditional tasks complete?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-4.5

I have a function that extracts values from an email header. To speed things up, wanted to use the async from framework 4.5. This is my first attempt to use async.

I am calling the extracting function asynchronously several times in succession to pull different values. From an email header. What I am having trouble with is how to know when all instances have completed. I found examples but none that fit my situation with conditional tasks.

I believe I need to:

- Dim a task array
- Add each necessary task to the array
- Afterward, use Task.WhenAll

But, I am not sure how to do it.

```
            'Extract these vars from header if no value was passed
            'Calling HeaderExtract Async for speed
            If Len(sClient) = 0 Then
                sClient = HeaderExtractAsync("Client,", sHeaders).Result
   ' --> Add this as a new task?
            End If
            If Len(sSubscriptionNum) = 0 Then
                sSubscriptionNum = HeaderExtractAsync("SubscriptionNum,", sHeaders).Result
            End If
            If Len(sTargetID) = 0 Then
                sTargetID = HeaderExtractAsync("TargetID,", sHeaders).Result
            End If
            If Len(sAddressBook) = 0 Then
                sAddressBook = HeaderExtractAsync("AddressBook,", strHeaders).Result
            End If

' --> Check that all are done?
```

Comment: Are you sure parallelizing this actually makes sense? Extracting a header doesn't sound like something that's CPU intensive.

Comment: There are about a dozen or more tags that I thought I could extract faster than synchronous method. I realize the gain is small here, but over thousands of records in a batch, it may add up? Also, I am using this as a learning opportunity as I have other places that would benefit from this…like… credit card batch process, email sending, etc.

Comment: What is the actual question?  You seem to know how to do it (use `Task.WhenAll()`, and even have code.  Have you tried it?  Does it not work?  Have you tried stepping through to understand why it's not working?

Comment: Aren't all those calls accessing the same data structures? Does it make sense paralleize this? At least, this way?
If you really, REALLY need to make it async, just create an async method ('Task.Run') that does that sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, how long does `HeaderExtract` take to run, there is a non-trivial amount of overhead to start up an async task and you may be making your program slower if `HeaderExtract` returns quickly.

2ndly, you are not getting any of the benefits of await, you need to call `Await Foo()` for it to give back control to the message pump, `Foo().Result` will stall your program and make your UI unresponsive (if this is on the ui thread)

Lastly, if it does take a while to complete you want to start all your tasks up ***then*** check for results, otherwise you will be waiting for the first result to come back before you even start looking for the 2nd result.

```
'Extract these vars from header if no value was passed
'start off all the tasks before we start checking for results
If Len(sClient) = 0 Then
    tClient = HeaderExtractAsync("Client,", sHeaders)
End If
If Len(sSubscriptionNum) = 0 Then
    tSubscriptionNum = HeaderExtractAsync("SubscriptionNum,", sHeaders)
End If
If Len(sTargetID) = 0 Then
    tTargetID = HeaderExtractAsync("TargetID,", sHeaders)
End If
If Len(sAddressBook) = 0 Then
    tAddressBook = HeaderExtractAsync("AddressBook,", strHeaders)
End If

'now start waiting for results
If tClient IsNot Nothing
    sClient = Await tClient
If tSubscriptionNum IsNot Nothing
    sSubscriptionNum = Await tSubscriptionNum
If tTargetID IsNot Nothing
    sTargetID = Await tTargetID
If tAddressBook IsNot Nothing
    sClsAddressBookient = Await tAddressBook
```

If you rather the thread to sleep instead of doing an await (like you are not using .NET 4.5 and you just used the wrong tag in your OP) replace the `sFoo = await tFoo` lines with `sFoo = tFoo.Result`

Comment: I did not think much about overhead. (I read that task were less expensive than traditional threads.) Your comment caused me to do more research. I would strongly recommend this article for any newbie. It helped me clarify when/not to use async. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well. You seems to be using async programming but you're not using it at all, first I recommend you to read about this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/24/diving-deep-with-winrt-and-await.aspx and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/06/14/exposing-net-tasks-as-winrt-asynchronous-operations.aspx, these resources are intended for WinRT but you may get the picture.

Now, your method returns a `Task<TResult>` (which is fine), but by calling `Result` you are effectively making this synchronous, given that Result always waits for the Task to end before returning something. The way to make this asynchronous will be like this:

```
If Len(sClient) = 0 Then
    Dim tClient as Task(Of Whatever) = HeaderExtractAsync("Client,", sHeaders)
    tClient.Start()
End If
```

Then later check whether the task has finished or not like this:

```
If tClient.IsCompleted Then
    DoSomething()
Else
    ContinueWaiting();
End If
```

Probably you may want to put this in a loop so you can be sure that if the task has not completed you wait until it does.

**Edit:**

I realized that it seems that you want to use Tasks as Threads, even while you can do it, Tasks are not perfect for this purpose, Task are meant more for triggering an activity that may take a while to complete, then when it completes it will return the control to the calling function exactly where it left it off all without blocking the main thread (which usually is the UI thread), taking this in mind you can also read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benwilli/archive/2013/04/24/tasks-are-not-threads.aspx, and here is an example about how to properly use a Task, assuming `HeaderExtractAsync` takes a while to complete:

```
If Len(sClient) = 0 Then
    sClient  = Await HeaderExtractAsync("Client,", sHeaders)
End If
```

Comment: For async-await you don't need to call `Start()`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i know you can use await, but for the look of it, it seems that he is trying to use Tasks as Threads.

Comment: No, you are using it wrong too, why wait for the result of the first one before you start the 2nd one, the awaits should be after you start all the tasks up.